# Callisthénie : est-il courant ?

Tags: sport

> Je pratique la callisthénie au quotidien.

Selon [cntrl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/callisth%C3%A9nie#:%7E:text=CALLISTH%C3%89NIE%2C%20substantif-,CALLISTH%C3%89NIE%2C%20subst.,enfants%20et%20des%20jeunes%20filles.) c'est un mot rare. Cependant, vue que le dictionnaire date des années de 1990, je me demande si l'on peut l'utiliser couramment (bien sûr avec cette [signification](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisth%C3%A9nie)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne connaissais même pas le mot. Après avoir lu l'article correspondant de Wikipédia j'ai vu que c'était un mot popularisé d'abord aux États-Unis dans la deuxième moitié du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Il ne figure pas dans mon *Petit Robert* qui a plus de 50 ans ni dans mon *Grand Larousse* en 10 volumes qui a le même âge.

Plusieurs constatations :

- Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=callisth%C3%A9nie%20&year_start=1820&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3#) permet de constater que le mot connaît un regain de popularité à la fin du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle.
- Une recherche dans [un moteur de recherche](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=callisth%C3%A9nie%20&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&tbs=) montre que le terme est actuellement employé dans la presse spécialisée, mais  aussi plus grand public, avec des entrées relativement récentes.
- On voit que le terme est souvent employé sous son orthographe anglaise même en français ([par exemple](https://calisthenics-france.blogspot.com/p/routines.html)).

En conclusion de tout ce que j'ai pu lire, je dirais que le terme n'est pas employé de nos jours dans la définition donnée dans le TLF (ou dans le [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/callisth%C3%A9nie)<sup>1</sup>). S'il fut à l'origine, et pendant longtemps, employé pour ne parler que de l'exercice physique qui convenait aux jeunes filles pour leur faire acquérir des proportions harmonieuses visant à développer  leur pouvoir de séduction, il a acquis désormais un sens dans le domaine de la pratique sportive, et ce, quel que soit le sexe. Je pense qu'on peut dater cette évolution dans la dernière décennie 20<sup>e</sup> siècle quand la pratique sportive individuelle s'est fortement répandue et popularisée. L’évolution du sens du mot lui fait connaître un regain d'emploi, mais je ne pense pas cependant qu'il soit encore compris par un grand nombre de personnes. Certainement pas autant que *calisthenics* en anglais.

Enfin désormais quand je ferai mes squats quotidiens je dirai que je fais de la callisthénie !

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Je retiens cet exemple pour montrer la limite d'un ngram qui ne dit que ce qu'on veut bien lui faire dire et est très insuffisant à prouver quoi que ce soit.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**Callisthénie** est environ 1000 fois moins courant que **gymnastique** à l'écrit.

[image]

En dehors des spécialistes du domaine, il y a fort à parier que la majorité des gens n'ont, comme moi, jamais jusque là entendu ce mot.

Si on compare les popularités relatives de callisthénie et gymnastique en français et en anglais, on voit que la forme anglaise est environ dix fois moins rare que la française:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a absolument aucun problèmes ; c'est un mot rare, littéraire mais il est attesté. On peut toujours employer un mot littéraire dans la conversation, en particulier lorsqu'il ne semble pas en exister un autre.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/callisth%C3%A9nie)) Rare, LITT. Ensemble d'exercices de gymnastique appropriés au développement physique harmonieux des enfants et des jeunes filles.
> ♦ Le sport, j'ai tout pratiqué, y compris les nages de style, la callisthénie.  (A. Arnoux, Les Gentilshommes de ceinture,1928, p. 158)

Comment: Le terme de littéraire ne convient pas quand on voit que le mot  est employé sur des sites aussi populaires (au sens français de peuple) que ceux [d'un club sportif](https://www.wellness-sportclub.ch/blog/la-callisthenie-en-5-bienfaits/),  d'un [site qui s'appelle Croq'Kilos](https://www.croq-kilos.com/actus/la-callisthenie-quand-ton-corps-te-fait-maigrir), d'un [site féminin](https://www.aufeminin.com/sports-femme/callisthenie-exercices-s2907600.html) grand public, et  des dizaines d'autres.

Comment: @none C'est peut-être en passe de devenir du vocabulaire courant, mais pour l'instant ça ne l'est pas ; pourquoi s'interrogerait-on tant sur son usage présent ? Il peut rester dans la langue courante comme il peut très bientôt être abandonné pour un autre terme. Une hirondelle ne fait pas le printemps.

Comment: Je n'oppose pas littéraire à courant, j'oppose littéraire à populaire. Si un mot est employé par le peuple, il n'est pas littéraire (la langue littéraire est réservée à une élite instruite). Il peut y avoir des mots du peuple qui ne sont pas courants. C'est le cas de *callisthénie* qui peut être employé par des gens du peuple peu instruits littérairement mais qui connaissent ce mot parce qu'il tombe dans leur champ de compétence.

Comment: @None Vous avez là une notion particulière de « populaire » ; il ne me semble pas que ce mot dans l'usage qui ss dessine prenne des connotations populaires, c'est à dire plutôt grossières, mais au contraire, qu'il s'installe dans le vocabulaire en tant que terme de la langue courante sans connotations. Vous voulez peut-être dire qu'il est en train d'être vulgarisé ?

Comment: Populaire ne veut pas du tout dire grossier ! populaire c'est ce qui est accessible à tout le monde,  et pas seulement à une élite. Déjà dit.

Comment: @None (TLFi) LING. _populaire_  Qui est propre aux couches les plus modestes de la société, au peuple et qui est inusité par les gens cultivés et la bourgeoisie. Synon. vulgaire. _vulgaire_ − [En parlant de productions orales, du lang.]
♦ Qui choque la bienséance par son caractère grossier dans l'expression ou dans le contenu. Expression, langue, mot, parole, sens, terme vulgaire.

Comment: Tu peux choisir l'interprétation du mot populaire que tu veux, tu es complémentent hors sujet.  Le mot en question est « littéraire », et c'est toi qui l'emploie. Tu peux dériver et employer tous les chemins détournés que tu veux, tu ne me convaincras jamais qu'un mot qui est employé par des personnes dont la culture n'est pas littéraire peut être qualifié de **littéraire**.

Comment: @None Le dictionnaire le qualifie de littéraire ; cela signifie qu'il apparait dans une certaine partie du matériel écrit où il sera encore considéré comme littéraire par les gens qui lisent toujours ce matériel et qui ont été formés par ce matériel, jusqu'à ce que ces gens soient finalement conscient du nouvel usage qui se répand ; seulement, pour l'instant, ce nouvel usage n'est toujours pas très connu. Alors il me semble que pour une majorité c'estpour l'instant plutôt littéraire, comme le dit le TLFi.

Comment: Le dictionnaire date des années de 1990. Il même donne une définition tout a fait dépassée. Des nos jours, personne ne l'utilise pour désigner l'exercice physique qui convenait aux jeunes filles pour leur faire acquérir des proportions harmonieuses visant à développer leur pouvoir de séduction (merci @None):-)!

Comment: Il donne même et pas  Il même donne:-)!

Comment: À mon avis le mot en français dans son usage du jour est une réfection sur le modèle de l'emploi présumément [moderne](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/calisthenics) en anglais, soit l'exercice sans équipement (donc avec le poids du corps, les mouvements de gymnastique, flexions, tractions etc.). Je ne dirais pas qu'un gars comme Heria colle avec le style _littéraire_, ni que ce genre de monde-là désire recycler les exercices légers pour jeunes filles dont on discutait il y a un siècle et demi dans les salons de la haute (« The players warmed up for the game by doing calisthenics. »).

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Il n'y a pas vraiment à invoquer l'idée de glissement ; on constate au plus une évolution dans laquelle d'une particularisation au besoin des femmes, si l'on peut dire, on passe à une généralisation à ceux de tous (hommes, femmes, enfants) et  quel que soit l'ensemble des exercices modernes il s'agit toujours de force et de beauté. Ce que l'on a appelé la gymnastique depuis la Grèce  antique n'est plus aujourd'hui ce que c'était en Grèce. Il en est de même pour les Jeux Olympiques ; on utilise cependant les mêmes noms et ne tendons à considérer qu'une évolution.